# Python - os.environ.get not working in subprocess.Popen call

Tags: python, subprocess

I am using the python `os.environ.get()` call to get environment variables that I set in my `.bashrc` file.  If I call the python program directly from the command line it works fine. If I call the python program from another python program using the `subprocess.Popen()` call, all the environment variables are returned as `None`.  I have read some other posts where the environment is passed into the subprocess using `sub_env = os.environ.copy()` and then `subprocess.Popen("program_name", env=sub_env, shell=True)`, but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas as to why I cannot access my environment variables in a subprocess?

I have tried using `subprocess.Popen` as well as `os.system("program_name")` but neither works.

Comment: You need to export variables for them to be visible to subprocesses. (And of course make sure an interactive shell that ran `.bashrc` is an ancestor in the process tree of whatever process you expect to have access to variables set there; for processes started with a GUI or cron or in any other respect not by an interactive shell or by something itself started by an interactive shell you typically need to set variables another way; what that Right Way is depends on your OS, which as far as I know you aren't currently telling us).

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76689940/edit) your question to include a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with test data demonstrating your problem.

Comment: BTW, you certainly don't need `sub_env`; processes get a copy of their parent's environment _by default_; if you don't pass any `env` at all the child gets everything the parent had. Most likely your parent Python process doesn't have the variables you need either but you just haven't checked.

Comment: I have placed several EXPORT statements in my .bashrc file such as EXPORT SQL_SERVER_IP_ADDRESS="192.168.199.4". If I use the os.environ.get('SQL_SERVER_IP_ADDRESS) it returns the string '192.168.199.4'. When I call the python program that contains the os.environ.get from another python process using subprocess.Popen, None is returned. Is using the EXPORT statement in the .bashrc file what you mean by "you need to export variables for them to be visible in subprocesses"? BTW I am using Linux and calling the python program from the terminal (bash shell).